Raster Merge tool loses most of the output
I am having issues with the Raster Merge tool, the output seems to be missing most of the input layers. I have about 100 files that I need to merge into one layer to perform further tasks in QGIS. I have tried merging the files all together and then in smaller groups (even as little as 3 files), but it always seems to have lost most of the layers, sometimes the whole layer, sometimes just a part of it. The files I am using were of unknown CRS and of different pixel sizes, so I have used the Warp (Reproject) tool to change the CRS to the same for all (I compared with a different layer and the locations  were correct). Later, I have changed the pixel size to 10 (the files had a range of 10-50 pixel size). It didn't help, the output was the same. I have also tried changing the format from .tif to .map, and the output contained different layers, but it was still missing most of the expected output. The extents off all the layers are different. I'm not getting any error messages in the log. Would all this be caused by issues with the data itself? What can I do to fix it?
[

